# How this language has even number of symbols ((0+1)(0+1))*

Tags: regex, computation-theory

I am studying course for Automata, may be as a beginner I'm missing something , I am really confused with this regular expression as the teacher saying

> it represents a language with all binary strings having even number of
>   symbols

Alphabet Σ={0,1}

((**0**+**1**)(**0**+**1**))*

> (0+1) saying union of 0 and 1

but I am confused here let suppose 
first (0+1) gives 01 and second (0+1) gives only 0, then finally we concatenate both having (010)* and let it end up with only one occurrence i.e. 010

then how it has even number of symbols? need little understanding of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given Question: ((0+1)(0+1))*

Let's start from the innermost bracket **(0+1)**  this **matches with either 0 or 1 not 01**

**'+'** means **"or"** operator, this is not a conjunction operator.

and this is repeated twice hence **((0+1)(0+1))** matches with **01 or 10 or 00 or 11**

and **'*'** means it **matches 0 or more times**

Hence, ((0+1)(0+1))* matches with [NULL] or 01 or 10 or 00 or 11 or 0011 or 1100 or 1010 or 0110 ....so on

Answer (score 0):

Union means one or the other, not both. So, 0+1 would either be 0 or 1, but not both at the same time. Hence (0+1)(0+1) would result in either 00, 01, 10 or 11. All of them have even number of symbols. The result would follow.